# Partial Model Validation in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `PartialView` that is a form used to create or modify a user and implements the ViewModel `DynamicActionUserModel`.  The view that referrences this partialView shows a table of all `MembershipUsers` and gives the ability to create a new user `Membership.CreateUser()` or modify a user 'Membership.UpdateUser()`. The form in the partialView does an ajax post to my controller to submit data.

The issue I'm running into is that when a user is created their userName, email, *password* and role is serialized back to the controller as `DynamicActionUserModel.RegisterModel` and validated, but when a user is modified, password is not a property that is available (nor do I want to make it available to modify on the client side) so it isn't set in `DynamicActionUserModel.RegisterModel` and `ModelState.IsValid` is always false.

Perhaps the design of my model and view needs to change, or is there a way to validate the model but ignore password when a user is being modified? Not sure what the best practice is for this one.

I guess another option would be to create another ViewModel and another partialView specifically for modifying a user but that seems sloppy.

**Model**

```
public class DynamicActionUserModel {
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string[] SelectedRoles { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Roles { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateUser() {
    var model = new DynamicActionUserModel {
        Action = "CreateUser",
        RegisterModel = new RegisterModel {
            Roles = new MultiSelectList(System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles())
        }
    };

    return PartialView("_UserPartial", model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ModifyUser() {
    var model = new DynamicActionUserModel {
        Action = "ModifyUser",
        RegisterModel = new RegisterModel {
            Roles = new MultiSelectList(System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles())
        }
    };

    return PartialView("_UserPartial", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModifyUser(DynamicActionUserModel model) {
    bool isEqual = true;

    if(!ModelState.IsValid) { // this is always false because password is empty
        return PartialView("_UserPartial", model);
    }

    var user = Membership.GetUser(model.RegisterModel.UserName);
    // do stuff
    Membership.UpdateUser(user);

    return Json(new {success = false});
}
```

**View**

```
@using RobotDog.Models
@model IEnumerable<RobotDog.Models.UserModel>

<!-- table of users -->
<div class="modify-form">
    @Html.Action("ModifyUser")
</div>
<div class="create-user-form">
    @Html.Action("CreateUser")
</div>
```

**PartialView**

```
@model RobotDog.Models.DynamicActionUserModel

@using(Html.BeginForm(Model.Action,"Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajax" })) {
    <!-- Email -->
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegisterModel.Email, new { @class = inputSize, placeholder = "Email"})

    <!-- UserName -->
    @if(Model.Action == "ModifyUser") {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RegisterModel.UserName)
        <span class="input-xlarge uneditable-input">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.RegisterModel.UserName)</span>
    } else {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegisterModel.UserName, new { @class = inputSize, placeholder = "User Name" })
    }

    <!-- Password -->
    @if(Model.Action == "Createuser") {
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.RegisterModel.Password, new { @class = inputSize, placeholder = "Password"})
    }

    <!-- Roles -->
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.RegisterModel.SelectedRoles, Model.RegisterModel.Roles)

    <!-- Submit -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `ModelState.Remove("password")` before calling `ModelState.IsValid`, but as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6843241/118447) if a property is not always required you should not mark it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`ModelState.IsValidField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalidfield%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) ?

> Note: even as of MVC4 the documentation is backwards and should say :
>
> Determines whether there are any ModelError objects that are associated with or prefixed with the specified key.

I've made a little extension method helper for this:

```
public static class ModelStateHelpers
    {
        public static bool IsValidFor<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model,
                                                         System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                                         ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

            return modelState.IsValidField(name);
        }
    }
```

Usage is simple:

```
 bool billingValid = model.IsValidFor(x => x.CheckoutModel.BillingAddress, ModelState);
```