# Validating a MVC3 viewmodel object based on a selected condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I want to do some conditional validation for a view model I have created.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public Item Item1 { get; set; }
    public DetailedItem Item2 { get; set; }

}

public class Item
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DetailedItem
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a radiobutton bound to SelectedItem that via clientside shows or hides a partial view bound to Item & DetailedItem.

On form post I want to validate the selected model but how. If I were to use the above code and do a

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

With only one of the partial views fully completed I would get a IsValid=false due to the other modal not containing the required fields.

Is there a way to only validate only the selected model?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ModelState is a Dictionary class and you can remove an item from it using a Key.

For example,

```
ModelState.Remove("Item1");
```

Then a call to

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

will ignore requirements of that entry.

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470162%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and there is also some [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843171/is-it-correct-way-to-use-modelstate-remove-to-deal-with-modelstate) about whether this *should* ever occur in your ViewModels or not.

Comment: Thanks Dan. To easy when you know how